# Using generic class as a parameter in method

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

Ok, I am working on a binary LoadSave system, and I just ran into a small issue.  I have a generic class that serializes a dictionary (since it isn't possible to do this in unity yet) and I am trying to use it as a parameter for a method, but I can't figure out how to do it yet.

My serializeable dictionary is :

```
public class DCGSerializeableDict<TKey, TValue> : ScriptableObject where TKey: IEquatable<TKey>{}
```

*Full code for this is [HERE](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/460727/how-to-serialize-dictionary-with-unity-serializati.html). (very bottom of the page)*

and I am trying to use it as a parameter like so:

```
private void SaveClass(DCGSerializeableDict<T,T> save,string name){}
```

Any suggestion on how to go about this? Or is this not possible and I should find another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to put T after the method name:

```
private void SaveClass<T>(DCGSerializeableDict<T,T> save,string name){}
```